# Use SSH to mysql_connect with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ssh, laravel

I need to connect to a certain server and insert stuff into the database from another webapp

In order to do so, I need to have full SSH access.

The steps follows
1. $articles = Article::all();
2. Create an SSH tunnel
3. mysql_connect(remote) -> mysql_select_db -> mysql_query(insert $articles) -> mysql_close

It's possible with php's built in ssh2:s functions.

--

Now, my question is. What is the best way to do this using smart features in Laravel?

Could etc Laravels SSH::run functionality be of any productive use here? Maybe a reccommended way would be to create models for the foreign database?

Edit: I need this to be done differently for all environments also. I have different private SSH keys on the server and localhost etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your server, you can use Laravel [remote component](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Remote)

Fortrabbit has awesome SSH workflow. They allow you to work remotely with your app and with you database.

UPDATE:

Remote component is a provider for Laravel SSH capabilities. It allows you to work remotely with your application. All setting must be done in **app/config/remote.php** file. There you have to enter you server credentials. Take a look at **Remote** package in Laravel.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive about the remote component? Did you use this yourself? How?

Answer (score 0):

best way would be to configure mysql to allow your machine to connect to it in my opinion.

Comment: Had a talk with the hosting provider and this is not an option, sorry